# Use a variable-object that was given as an argument

Tags: php

I have some classes that sometimes should connect to the database during the same request. The solution I thought about was to give the PDO Object as an argument to the methods. There is a class that DB() that creates the connection and stores into a public attribute:

```
class DB{
    public $conn;
    public function DB(){
        $this->conn = new PDO(...);//missed :S thxs!
    }
}

class Foo{
    public function Foo($db[, $more_possible_variables]){
        //implementing some stuff with $db
    }
}

/*index.php*/
require_once 'DB.php';
require_once 'Foo.php';

$db = new DB();
$foo = new Foo($db->conn);
/*End of index*/
```

I tried some ideas to make this work, but I always get the error that is not possible to handle a variable like an object. I have other solutions, but they are not recommended from an efficiency point of view...

Comment: Make sure you are not missing an $this->conn there. You are assigning the PDO Object to a local variable without this.

Comment: I found that I had the same mistake into my code!

Answer (score 0):

First off, make sure you are not missing the object reference *$this* there, otherwise you would be assigning the PDO Object to a local variable instead of the member variable.

As a good design practice you should consider using a design pattern like the Singleton, which would guarantee that only 1 instance of the PDO Object would be created for each request in this case.

You can see an sample implementation of this in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton).

This would be a simplified version of what you are trying to achieve:

```
class DB {
    private static $_Instance = null;
    protected $_PDOInstance = null;

    private function __construct() {
        // Create the PDO Object
        $this->_PDOInstance = new PDO(...);
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$_Instance !== null) {
            return self::$_Instance;
        }

        $className = __CLASS__;
        self::$_Instance = new $className;

        return self::$_Instance;
    }
}
```

To learn more about design patterns and how they are used you may want to head to the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) on the matter, or read an amazing book like the GoF - Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software.